# Measure difference between two files

Tags: file, video, compression, comparison

I have a question that's very specific, yet very general at the same time. (Also, I don't know if this is quite the right site for this.)

## The Scenario

Let's say I have an uncompressed video `vid.avi`. It is then run through `[Some compression algorithm]`, which is lossy. I want to compare `vid.avi` and the new, compressed file to determine just how much data was lost in the compression. How can I compare the files and how can I measure the difference between the two, using the original as the reference point? Is it possible at all? I would prefer a generic answer that will work with any language, but I would also gladly accept an answer that's specific to a language.

**EDIT:** Let me be more specific. I want something that compares two video files in a similar way that the Notepad++ Compare plugin compares text files. I just want to find out how close each individual pixel's colour is to the original file's colour for that pixel.

Thanks in advance, and thank you for taking the time to read this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally the change in video quality that people want to measure when comparing compression methods, rather than a loss of data.

If you did want to measure somehow the data loss, you would have to define what you mean by 'data' and how you wanted to measure it. Video compression is quite complex and the approach may even differ frame by frame within a video. Data could mean the colour depth for each pixel, the number of frames per second, whether a frame is encoded based on a delay to other frames etc.

Video quality is subjective so the reduction in quality after compression will not be an absolute value. The usual way to measure the quality is similar to the technique used for audio - Mean Opinion Score: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_opinion_score. Its essentially uses a well defined process to try to apply some objectivity to a test audiences subjective experience.

Comment: Exactly right. You can calculate, for example, the RMS difference between two images, but that will not tell you what you want to know. Two images can have a large RMS difference, but look almost identical to a human.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had already known about Mean Opinion Score, but it's not quite what I'm going for. Really, I want something that is the equivalent of comparing two text files and highlighting the differences, but for video files. I suppose I should rephrase my question to include that.